# Ruby Google::Auth::WebUserAuthorizer throw undefined get method exception

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, google-auth-library-ruby

Below is example code which i am running:

```
require 'googleauth'
require 'googleauth/web_user_authorizer'
require 'googleauth/stores/redis_token_store'
require 'redis'

client_id = Google::Auth::ClientId.from_file('/path/to/client_secrets.json')
scope = ['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive']
token_store = Google::Auth::Stores::RedisTokenStore.new(redis: Redis.new)
authorizer = Google::Auth::WebUserAuthorizer.new(client_id, scope, token_store, '/oauth2callback')


get('/authorize') do
  # NOTE: Assumes the user is already authenticated to the app
  user_id = request.session['user_id']
  credentials = authorizer.get_credentials(user_id, request)
  if credentials.nil?
    redirect authorizer.get_authorization_url(login_hint: user_id, request: request)
  end
  # Credentials are valid, can call APIs
  # ...
end

get('/oauth2callback') do
  target_url = Google::Auth::WebUserAuthorizer.handle_auth_callback_deferred(
    request)
  redirect target_url
end
```

and above code throw's "NoMethodError: undefined method `get' " error

Comment: Gem details: https://github.com/googleapis/google-auth-library-ruby